# MFMailComposeViewController recent address

Tags: ios, xcode, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I would like to send a mail to an user using MFMailComposeViewController but without saving the address to recents by the MailApp. So when a new user taps the letter "a" it should not show any recent address that start with the letter "a".

Is there an option to disable saving to recent addresses ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `MFMailComposeViewController` is a component that is supposed to be used "as it is".

You can't change its behaviour, I'm afraid.

If that's what you want to do, you should implement your own "mail compose" view controller with your custom logic.